# Enet Multiplayer Game not connecting over the internet

Tags: c++, networking, game-development, multiplayer, enet

I am trying to make a multiplayer 2d shooter game using Enet. I wanted to test its networking capabilities with a friend. It uses a hybrid p2p and p2c architecture (A player can host a game, kinda like LAN worlds in minecraft, if you know what I mean). He gave me his IP and I tried to join his hosted game but my client couldn't connect.

I tried looking at how assault cube does its networking, but I found no answer.

This is how I connect:

```
bool connectToServer(ENetHost *&client, ENetPeer *&server, int32_t &cid, std::string ip, char *playerName)
{
    ENetAddress adress;
    ENetEvent event;

    if (ip.empty())
    {
        enet_address_set_host(&adress, "127.0.0.1");
    }
    else
    {
        enet_address_set_host(&adress, ip.c_str());
    }
    //enet_address_set_host(&adress, "95.76.249.14");
    //enet_address_set_host(&adress, "192.168.1.11");
    adress.port = 7778;

    //client, adress, channels, data to send rightAway
    server = enet_host_connect(client, &adress, SERVER_CHANNELS, 0);

    if (server == nullptr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //see if we got events by server
    //client, event, ms to wait(0 means that we don't wait)
    if (enet_host_service(client, &event, 5000) > 0
        && event.type == ENET_EVENT_TYPE_CONNECT)
    {
        std::cout << "connected\n";
    }
    else
    {
        enet_peer_reset(server);
        return false;
    }


    if (enet_host_service(client, &event, 5000) > 0
        && event.type == ENET_EVENT_TYPE_RECEIVE)
    {
        Packet p = {};
        size_t size;
        auto data = parsePacket(event, p, size);
                // Handshake
        if (p.header != headerReceiveCIDAndData)
        {
            enet_peer_reset(server);
            return false;
        }

        cid = p.cid;

        glm::vec3 color = *(glm::vec3 *)data;
        auto e = phisics::Entity();
        e.pos = getSpawnPosition();
        e.lastPos = e.pos;
        e.color = color;
        memcpy(e.name, playerName, playerNameSize);
        players[cid] = e;

        sendPlayerData(e, true);

        std::cout << "received cid: " << cid << "\n";
        enet_packet_destroy(event.packet);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        enet_peer_reset(server);
        return 0;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Is your friend in Bucharest? Do you think they'd be happy having you publish their IP here for possible exploitation? In order for you to connect, they must open port 7778 on their router and port-forward to their computer via NAT or similar. Or use UPnP if the router supports it. It's generally not a great idea to open ports. _Especially_ when you don't know what you're doing, which in this case seems plausible.

Comment: Erm, no. And now I understand you need to port forward it. My friend knows how to port forward actually, so he does actually know what he's doing. Thanks for the answer!